# Write a combination of two sentences using the word "respectively"

Tags: sentence-combination

I want to combine the following sentences:

- The first column shows the variable names.
- The second column shows the description of the variables.

Which of the following are correct?

a. The first and the second column each show the variable names and the description of the variables, respectively.

b. The first and the second column each shows the variable names and the description of the variables, respectively.

c. The first and the second column show the variable names and the description of the variables, respectively.

d. The first and the second column shows the variable names and the description of the variables, respectively.

Or, maybe do you have any better suggestions?

I think the correct answer is **a** because I read in another source and it says "they each have ...." That sentence implies that the verb  remain without s. But my concern is whether the rule still applies to the sentence if the sentence is added with "respectively" ?

Comment: Which answer do  _you_ think is correct, and why? It will help us to provide a useful answer if you use the **[edit]** link to add that to your question.

Answer (score 1):

As @Phil14 commented, answer **C** is indeed correct.

- The first and the second column show the variable names and the description of the variables, respectively.

"**[Respectively](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/respectively)**" means "*(of two or more items) with each relating to something previously mentioned, in the same order as first mentioned*"

So if the *first item* = **first column** and the *second item* = **second column** then "**respectively**" should relate only the *variable names to the first column* (first in order) and only the *description of the variables to the second column* (second in order).

This means that it agrees with the statements:

- The first column shows the variable names.
- The second column shows the description of the variables.

Answer **A** doesn't agree because of the determiner "**each**":

- The first and the second column each show the variable names and the description of the variables, respectively.

Which means that "*every column shows both the variable names and the description of the variables*" and this doesn't agree with the statements mentioned earlier.

Answer **B** is incorrect because of the rule "*The pronoun each acts in apposition to a plural subject. In that case, the verb must be plural, for the grammatical subject always determines the number of the verb.*" ([Grammar.com](http://www.grammar.com/each-singular-or-plural/))

> - The *coach and the quarterback* each **want** to win the championship.

Comment: You are welcome. Don't accept the answer, yet. Wait 24 to 48 hours before accepting an answer as someone might give a better explanation.